# How would you prove if another graph is isomorphic to the Petersen graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have been wondering how would you prove if a graph is isomorphic to the Petersen graph. I tried to mark the vertices in such a way that they would carry the same edge and vertex relationship as the Petersen graph but when I have to label the last vertex it does not match the relationship of the Petersen graph. How would I try to prove this then? Take a look at the example below.
[image]

How would you check if the graph in the bottom left corner or any graph was isomorphic to the Petersen graph in the top left.

Comment: Isn't the last graph what you get it you "twist" the inner pentagram of the first one a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm a graph **is** isomorphic to Petersen; then I'd find a five-cycle in it and label it as $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_1$. I'd let $B_1,\ldots,B_5$ be the other vertices
adjacent to $A_1,\ldots,A_5$ respectively. If these are joined up as $B_1B_3B_5B_2B_4B_1$ then the graph is Petersen.

Comment: Thank you! This actually makes a lot more sense than the brute force method.